# How can we compress image from Image location and move file to Amazon s3 in php with WAF blocks

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-waf

I have an online image location(URL) which I have to upload to Amazon S3.
If I upload an image which has only 1-2 MB size the WAF not block the image but for the large size image like greater than 5-6 MB than the Amazon WAF blocks the image and gives the `403 forbidden error` to the uploader, if I upload the same image through any uploader plugin with chunking then no error will be given by WAF so how can I move file from online image location to Amazon S3.

I have tried this below code to save file but it takes too much time for large images to save the file on my server.

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-30mb.jpg');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$jsonData = base64_encode(curl_exec($curlSession));
$file = base64_to_jpeg($jsonData,'scarletwitch.jpg');
```